# How do I add fade in/out too this txt changing loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What you see runs currently, but simply changes the txt.
As you can see I have attempted to make the text fade in and out per each change.
Quite frankly Im lost as to how I should approach this; there must be a simply addition to my code. Looking around I have only seen example that would involve me starting completely over.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var slogan = [];
            slogan[0] = "Canopy Sports";
            slogan[1] = "Ads";
            slogan[2] = "Vidoes";
            slogan[3] = "Shananigans";

                    var newSlogan = document.getElementById("slogan");

            // generate a # between 1 &4
            function generateRandomNumber(){
                return Math.floor(Math.random()*slogan.length)+1;
            }

            function updateslogan () { 
                // var interval = generateRandomNumber();
                newSlogan.innerHTML = slogan[generateRandomNumber()-1]
            }


            updateslogan();

            function getNew () {
                // var interval = generateRandomNumber();
                fade = $(updateslogan).fadeIn("slow", function(){
      $(this).fadeOut("slow")
    });
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

            setInterval(getNew,4000);
});
```

I have to use fade in/out, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slogan = [
        "Canopy Sports",
        "Ads",
        "Vidoes",
        "Shananigans"
    ],
    newSlogan = $("#slogan");

    function getNew() {
        newSlogan.html(slogan[Math.floor(Math.random() * slogan.length)])

        newSlogan.fadeIn("slow", function () {
                $(this).fadeOut("slow")
        });
    }

    setInterval(getNew, 4000);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hL9UB/)

Comment: Beautiful! It looks so cool! And your code is much cleaner than my approach; Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method

```
$(this).fadeToggle();
```

this will make it fade in or fade out per each change.